# Trying to get headset to work in CentOS Linux

Tags: linux, audio, headphones, alsa, headset

I am trying to get my headset (Logitech H390) to work on a new Linux installation (CentOS 6.4). Unfortunately I am unable to hear anything from the headset. I have tried several options from the sound configuration window with no result (`kmod-alsa` installed)

Tried Google, but no luck there, since the 2 solutions I found require the kernel to be recompiled.

Is there a simpler solution to this problem?

**Update**: After using the headset I cannot hear anything! Something is definitely wrong with the sound card/and or the drivers.

Comment: Do you have a kernel version that *needs* to be recompiled?

Comment: No i don't. I am looking for an alternative solution.

Comment: OT: CentOS may not be a good idea for desktop use. Lots of packages are not up-to-date, and lots of (desktop use) packages are missing from repos.

Comment: Ubuntu, Fedora or OpenSuSE seem like a better option for a beginner. Try starting up `pavucontrol` or `alsamixer` in the console. Maybe the volume is just down.

Comment: sound card?  do you have one installed?  sound cards and USB headsets are two separate audio devices.  You might have the sound card enabled and the USB headset disabled.

Comment: @Keltari: Thanks for the info. I don't have a sound card i use the motherboard's Intel Audio which i can see when running $ cat /proc/asound/cards. Now i have another problem! After connecting the USB headset I cannot hear anything from the speakers!

Comment: Linux isnt my forte, and I dont have a box in front of me.  But from what I can remember you need to go into the ALSA mixer and make sure the right devices are enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Try running

```
sudo alsamixer
```

in a terminal, then press F6, select your headset (there should be a list of sound cards) and look at the volume bar.

If there is a 'MM' there, it's on mute.
Press the 'M' key to unmute it.

If it's not on mute according to alsamixer, run `pavucontrol` from a terminal, and a GUI window similar to this should pop up.[image: pavucontrol picture]
(my choice of styling makes it look a bit weird)

Once you have this window open, go to the configuration tab, and set everything that is not your headset, to "off".

Then, go to the output tab, and check your headset device is not muted, or on "silence".

Select the volume you want, and test it.

If none of that works, you may have missing alsa/pulseaudio dependencies. I don't know what the package manager for CentOS is, but if it's aptitude, you can run:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

This will satisfy dependencies.